# Home button and back to app in a newly installed app loads the initial activity again

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm encountering the following scenario in my application:

- Installing it and immediately opening it (using the open button
  after the installation, instead of the icon in the applications
  list).
- Navigating through a few activities.
- Clicking the home button.
- Clicking the application icon to load it again.
- Instead of returning to the activity I was in, the initial activity
  is loaded. The previous activity is still there and can be accessed by clicking the back button, but there isn't really a way to know that and it looks like the app was completely restarted.

This may be an issue in this app, because in some cases it might require a registration after performing a few actions, and losing the focus on the activity could be very annoying

Is there anything that can be done to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of flags under Intent that might be helpful.  You use them when an Activity is launched:

"**FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME**: If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause a newly launching task to be placed on top of the current home activity task (if there is one).

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT**: If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT did not seem to make a difference, and I could not find Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME.